# Is it possible to fetch data with Google Ads API for others ads?

Tags: api, google-ads-api

So in short, my task is to extract data from Google, and I'm curious if it's possible to fetch data using Google Ads API for different customers without all the required keys (developer token, refresh token, client_id and client secret). Is this possible or not? If yes, what privileges do I need, and what are the steps? If you know where I can find some clear documentation about this, it will be a lifesaver.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't possible unless you have MCC credentials and the account is within that. Otherwise you will need to get credentials for each account.